# Ruby On Rails, Postgresql - Date_Part or Extract for every minute group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by

I'm looking for a way of getting a grouped output for every minute records are being made. I'm looking for a result that would look something like this:

```
{"2015-01-05 12:05" => 5, "2015-01-05 12:06" => 2}
```

When using `DATE_PART` or `EXTRACT` I get this as result

```
{0.0=>1, 48.0=>2, 23.0=>3, 42.0=>2, 47.0=>2, 54.0=>1, 46.0=>2, 2.0=>1, 44.0=>2, 45.0=>2, 53.0=>1, 6.0=>3, 49.0=>1, 56.0=>2, 22.0=>1, 51.0=>1, 43.0=>2, 24.0=>2, 5.0=>1, 7.0=>1, 37.0=>2, 33.0=>2, 50.0=>1, 1.0=>2}
```

This is my code:

```
Model.group("DATE_PART('minute', created_at)").count
Model.group("EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM created_at)").count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Model.group("to_char(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')").count
```

Comment: Nice, thx. During the 10 minutes I found this gem if anyone else is intrested:

https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Comment: @Philip No problem. `groupdate` looks pretty nice actually and it seems to handle more edge cases, I'd go with that instead :).